# Variable does not exist in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following problem on my symfony2 project:

This is the code of my controller

```
public function showCustomerAction($id) {
    // retrieve the customer from the database
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $customer = $em->getRepository('VictorIoSiteBundle:Customer')->find($id);

    //throw new \Exception($customer);
    return $this->render('VictorIoSiteBundle:Site:viewCustomer.html.twig', array('customer' => $customer));
}
```

And the code of my twig view (quite simple):

```
{% if customer is defined %}
    <h3>Customer: {{ customer }} </h3>
{% endif %}
```

Finally my routing.yml

```
victor_io_site_show_customer:
pattern: /show-customer/{id}
defaults: { _controller: VictorIoSiteBundle:Site:showCustomer }
requirements:
    id: \d+
```

Now when I go on

```
http://localhost/Garage/web/app_dev.php/show-customer/46
```

I get the following error :

```
Variable " customer " does not exist in VictorIoSiteBundle:Site:viewCustomer.html.twig at line 2
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like a characters issue. There are fake spaces [**char(194)**](https://eval.in/56191) in your `{{ customer }}`.
Try just removing them and add a real space instead.

This character occurs when you hit <kbd>**Alt Gr**</kbd> + <kbd>**Space**</kbd> (it happens to me alot)

**Hints**

- TWIG ignores spaces and wouldn't result in an error if there was a real space issue
- Mostly, when you see

  > Variable "foo " does not exists

  it means you have this character after the `foo` variable