# Symfony2/Twig: Error on conditionally render

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to render a form on a twig template if its is defined in the render call on controller. Something like:

```
{% if form_to_be_rendered is defined %}
   {{ form(form_to_be_rendered) }}
{% endif }
```

If the controller's render call includes the var of `form_to_be_rendered`, everything runs well, and the form is rendered. But if I try to render the template without this argument, Twig throws a `RuntimeError` indicating that the `form_to_be_rendered` variable is not defined.

```
Variable "form_to_be_rendered" does not exist in BundleName:Path/to/template:template.html.twig at line 3
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
```

I've tried passing it as a null value and `is not null` check on condition, but it fails too.

I put this dump on template:

```
{% dump reset_password_form is defined %}
```

And it is evaluated as `false` when I don't pass any arguments to render function.

**EDIT**

I forgot to post that there is a `{% block content %}` inside the conditional block which causes the issue. Please view the solution below.

Thanks,

Comment: Just to rule out obvious things, that's the only place you use that variable, right? So we can be sure it's not being used somewhere else without the `if <var> is defined` guard

Comment: Yeah. I mean the var is only used inside the conditional block of course

Comment: The second line of your code (call to `form` function) should use expression delimiters (`{{ }}`) rather than tag delimiters (`{% %}`) though I would expect `Twig_Error_Syntax` instead of `Twig_Error_Runtime` if that were the primary issue

Comment: You are right. It's my fault when copying the code. Edited on the OP

Comment: Which line is number three? The one with `if` or `form()`?

Comment: Line number 3 is the `if` statement

Comment: Is the actual name of your form variable `form_to_be_rendered`? If you're using something else like `if some_object.form is defined` you could get an error if `some_object` is undefined.

Comment: Yes. When I want a form to be rendered, I pass an array containing a key named `form_to_be_rendered`. But when I don't, I pass an empty array.

Comment: Can you show how you pass the values to Twig in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

It's pretty weird and my fault since I don't post the full code on the OP.

```
{% if form is defined %}
    {% block content%}
        {{ form(form)}}
    {% end block %}
{% endif %}
```

The conditional block has inside a `{% block content %}` that Twig tries to render even the condition is evaluated to false. If I surround the conditional block with the content block, the issue is resolved.

```
{% block content%}
    {% if form is defined %}
        {{ form(form)}}
    {% endif %}
{% end block %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
{% if form_to_be_renderer|length %}
    {{ form(form_to_be_renderer) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I try this approach and the result is the same, a RuntimeError

Answer (score 0):

Twig documentation says:

defined:

> defined checks if a variable is defined in the current context.

empty:

> evaluates to true if the foo variable is null, false, an empty array, or the empty string.

null:

> null returns true if the variable is null.

So figure out, what exactly you want to check, depending on what value "form_to_be_rendered" can have.

Comment: I want to check if a variable called `form_to_be_rendered` exists in the arguments set passed by controller to twig on render call. The better approach, I think it's the first one, `defined`, but an error is thrown as I told on te OP.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495222/variable-does-not-exist-in-symfony2

Comment: This is weird. Try to rename the variable (in the twig template) to something completely else and see if the error appears. Cause usually you should be able to check for anything like {% if someArray.bla.arlasdjf is defined %} without any errors.