# Symfony variable does not exist in twig

Tags: php, symfony

I have these two entities `Users.php` and `sprovider.php` and a `UserController.php`
The thing that bothers me is the result when I try to render a template in this function.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/sproviderhome", name="sprovider_home")
 */
public function sproviderHomeAction(Request $request){

    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    $user= $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')->
        findOneBy(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));

    $jobs = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:jobs')
        ->findAll();

    if($user){
        return $this->render('home/sprovider.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'jobs' => $jobs,
        ));
    }else{
        return $this->render('home/login.html.twig', array(
            'message' => "Sorry, you need to login first.",
        ));
    }
}
```

Result in `sprovider.html.twig`:

> Variable "jobs" does not exist in home/sprovider.html.twig at line 8

**sprovider.html.twig:**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% if user is defined %}
        <h2 class="page-header">Welcome {{ user.name }}</h2>
    {% endif %}

    {% for job in jobs %}
        {{ job.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The strange thing here is that `$user` exists but `$jobs` does not.

What I tried so far is to dump the `jobs` and there is no problem, the jobs are in the variable.

Another thing I tried is to pass a string like this:

```
return $this->render('home/sprovider.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'jobs' => 'jobs',
        ));
```

Same result. Looks like its rendering only the first object which is strange because I am passing an `array()`. Am I missing something important? Can this have something to do with `cache`? I cleared both browser and doctrine cache, still nothing. I can't think of anything else to cause this. In other functions in the same controller I have had no problem rendering an array.

Comment: are you sure your query is actually returning an array? also, make sure you use an initial Capital letter for all your class names.

Comment: That's the thing. It looks like it's not. How can I be sure?

Comment: Can you debug the value of $jobs before it is set to twig? This is too make sure it is an array as expected.

Comment: check the typo `job.name` instead of `jobs.name`

Comment: @Matteo tried that. no result.

Comment: call `{{ dump($jobs) }}` somewhere and check it

Comment: Hi @GeorgiGeorgiev yes is not the solutions but only a minor bug

Comment: Do you get the same error if you change the 'jobs' variable to something else? ie 'myJobs'

Comment: @DevDonkey just tried that. Same thing. Does not exist in twig.

Comment: @LewisSpears just tried. No change.

Comment: I think `->getRepository('AppBundle:jobs')` is the problematic line. After bundle the name of the entity should be put which will be a uppercase word. Try `->getRepository('AppBundle:Jobs')` and clear your cache. It will work I believe.

Comment: @HimelNagRana did not work.

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev, Totally confused why this is happening. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495222/variable-does-not-exist-in-symfony2 can be a possible reason but chance seems less.

Comment: @HimelNagRana it's not that either. I managed to get to this conclusion : request->get() is somehow making `jobs` not render in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this. I am using a login form that checks the type of user before redirecting to different "homepage". Turns out I was not passing the checked `user` to this `sproviderHome` function but directly rendering the `sprovider.html.twig` with only one variable passed -> `user`.

**Solution 1**

Add

```
$jobs = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:jobs')
        ->findAll();
```

to the login function and pass both `user` and `jobs`, then get rid of the `sproviderHome` function.

**Solution 2** *neater solution*

Instead of `return $this->render(........)` in the login function, I used

```
return $this->forward('AppBundle:User:sproviderHome', array(
                'user'=>$user
            ));
```

and then add `$user` as a parameter to the `sproviderHome` function. Then add

```
$jobs = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:jobs')
        ->findAll();
```

in the function and it's all good. Also get rid of `Request $request` as an argument and remove those two lines

```
 $email = $request->get('email');
 $password = $request->get('password');
```

Apologies to those who tried their best with no result. My mistake for not mentioning the login functionality.

Answer (score 8):

You can make the loop safe in case there is no *jobs* variable defined placing a condition before.

```
{% if jobs is defined %}
    {% for job in jobs %}
        {{ job.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    No jobs found.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: the problem is there are actual jobs and the variable is defined. your answer helps me to render the page but not to display the jobs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first check if the job exists.

```
{% if jobs is defined %}
    {% for job in jobs %}
        {{ job.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    Something else
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**change**

```
{% for job in jobs %}
        {{ jobs.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
 {% for job in jobs %}
        {{ job.name }}
 {% endfor %}
```

**and**

```
$jobs = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:jobs')
    ->findAll();
```

to

```
$jobs = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Jobs')
        ->findAll();
```

It's could be better to add this too

```
{% if jobs is iterable %}
     {% for job in jobs %}
        {{ job.name }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: changed it. no effect.

Comment: Do you still get : Variable "jobs" does not exist in home/sprovider.html.twig at line 8 ?

Comment: Yes, Sir. Same thing.

Comment: I think user variable is not defined too but you didn't get the error with your if statement. You maybe forget to add AppBundle in your render method try  : AppBundle:home/sprovider.html.twig. Ofc, replace AppBundle with the name of your bundle

Comment: well, now i have nothing. The `white page of death`.

Comment: Where are your templates ? I means, they are in a Bundle or in app/Resources/views/ ?

Comment: user is going pretty well. It's working nice and smooth. If you check my twig file again you`ll notice that jobs is placed after user. + when i remove the {% for %} statement which includes jobs, the problem goes away. user works.

Comment: They are in app/Resources/views.

Comment: Ok well, you don't have Bundle that's why you get the page of death with AppBundle: . This is not a problem. Did you try {{ dump(jobs) }} ?

Comment: Yes. I removed the {%for%} loop completely, then tried to {{ dump(jobs) }}, same resulst. Does not exist.

Comment: This is weird, var_dump($jobs) before $this->rendrer(...) works?

Comment: It works fine. I think i managed to debug where the problem comes from. I made a new function in the controller that renders jobs and user in a new twig file. Works fine with email and password set as strings, not from request. As soon as I make the email and password to get the values from the request it all goes south. So, any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Jobs and email/password are independent. When you get from request and you dump them, you get email and password that you expected ? 
When you use $request->get(xxx) you get "Variable "jobs" does not exist" ?

Comment: Exactly. As soon as it comes to getting from request I get jobs does not exist. When i var dump email and pass i get what i expect

Comment: I need to see you all files to find what is wrong... Entities files, controller, templates... Thanks

Comment: [FILES](http://www.megafileupload.com/6ugf/symfonytest.rar) 

I am attaching an archive with the App and src folders. This should be enough.

Comment: {% extends '::base.html.twig' %} to {% extends 'base.html.twig' %} in sprovider.html.twig ?

Comment: still nothing. sorry.

Comment: I watched several times your code. Sorry there is a side effect that I did not find. I hope more informed people will find the answer.